# pthread_join success = thread entirely executed?

Tags: c, pthreads

I have a question about pthreads whith this little C source:

```
int calc = 0;

void func(void* data){
    calc = 2 * 2;
    return NULL;
}  

int main(){
    pthread_t t;
    if(0==pthread_create(&t,NULL,func,NULL)){
       if(0==pthread_join(t,NULL)){
           printf("Result: %d\n",calc);  // 4 ?
       }
    }
}
```

If pthread_join return success, is "func" always executed entirely ? (calc always equal 4 on printf ?).

Comment: What does the documentation of `pthread_join` say?

Comment: There is a typo in the function prototype, should be void* func(void* data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) returns zero on success.

The documentation says that [`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) blocks until the thread ends, so, with some applied logic one can easily conclude that the thread has ended.

On the other side, [`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) fails in different ways:

- When the handle is invalid: `EINVAL`
- When a deadlock has been detected: `EDEADLK`
- There is another possible error (recommended by the open group, but depending on the implementation): `ESRCH`, when it detects that the thread handle is being used past the end of the thread.

If you want to know more you may want to take a look at the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html).